# Random asterisk when using BibTeX and res.cls

Tags: bibliographies, cv, resume

I am using `res.cls` and commented out `\nofiles`. However when I use BibTeX for my publication list, I get this random * above the references. How do I remove this *?

```
\documentclass{res} 
\renewcommand{\refname}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{resume}
\section{\centerline{ \underline{SELECTED PUBLICATIONS}}}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{myPublications}
\bibliographystyle{aiaa} 
\end{resume} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since `res.cls` uses `\nofiles` I wonder how are you producing your bibliography...

Comment: @Medina I commented `\nofiles` out

Comment: It's not random, it's the remains of the `\nocite` command being misinterpreted. Does it happen when you use a different documentclass, like article? If you remove the `\nocite` command entirely, does the bibliography disappear?

Comment: @Mike Renfro: no, it's not the `\nocite` command being misiterpreted. See my answer.

Comment: My mistake. Could have sworn I'd seen something similar happen in the past, but I could have misinterpreted that, or the situation may have been entirely different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem comes from the line

```
\section*{\refname}
```

used inside the `thebibliography` environment as defined in `article.cls` (the base document class for `res.cls`). To prevent the asterisk, add the following lines to the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Perfect answer, asterisk gone!

Comment: You should also remove `natbib` as a package if you are using it.

Answer (score 2):

Discovered this answer purely accidentally. If you use [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132647/3989) answer (by the same author as the accepted answer in this question!) to suppress the "References" title that `\bibliography`generates, then this problem is automatically (auto-magically perhaps!) fixed. So, the overall solution looks cleaner. In the spirit of Tex.SE, am reproducing part of the answer here:

> Add these lines to the preamble:
>
> ```
> \usepackage{etoolbox}
> \patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*{\refname}}{}{}{}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Another method, that is a bit more hacky, is to basically cover the asterisk by placing a white colorbox behind the bibliography name then moving the bibliography up to cover the asterisk. For example,

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand\bibname{\vspace{-2em}\colorbox{white}{\large Citations}}
```