# How to remove the "References" title

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I would like to know how to remove the "References" title from command \bibliography{}.

If I write:

```
... text ... \cite{RefAnd2013} ...
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{AnderBib}
... more text ...
\end{document}
```

Appears "References" title:

> ... text [1] ...
>
> **References**
>
> [1] W. Anderson, Environment Modeling with UML, in ... 2010. [Online]. Available:
>   http://dx.doi.org/xxx
>
> ... more text ...

But, I need

> ... text [1] ...
>
> [1] W. Anderson, Environment Modeling with UML, in ... 2010. [Online]. Available:
>   http://dx.doi.org/xxx
>
> ... more text ...

Comment: Which document class are you using?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Add these lines to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*{\refname}}{}{}{}
```

A complete example:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{aaaaabbbbbb.bib}
@misc{test,
title= "The title",
howpublished= "Publisher"
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*{\refname}}{}{}{}

\begin{document}
\cite{test}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{aaaaabbbbbb}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since `IEEEtran.cls` automatically adds an entry for the references in the ToC, you might also be interested in suppressing this entry (after all, there's no section for the references); in this case, you will also have to add

```
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}}{}{}{}
```

Comment: Somehow doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 39):

If you don't mind using biblatex instead of bibtex, you could simply use the following: `\printbibliography[heading=none]`.

Dependencies:

- biblatex
- biblatex-ieee (for the IEEE bibliography style)

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Some section}
Some text \cite{KandR}.

\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

For the sake of completeness, here is the content of the refs.bib file used:

```
@BOOK
  {KandR,
   AUTHOR    = {Kernighan, Brian W. and Ritchie, Dennis M.},
   TITLE     = {The C Programming Language Second Edition},
   PUBLISHER = {Prentice-Hall, Inc.},
   YEAR      = 1988
  }
```

After compiling the document with `latexmk -bibtex -pdf`, the result should look like this:

[image: Result]

Comment: Give me a example, because this did not work for me.

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems this option is only available using biblatex instead of bibtex. I will update my answer with this information and a basic usage example.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, even with biblatex.

Answer (score 18):

If you are using the `natbib` package

```
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{}
```

will do the job.

Comment: This really a useful command.

Answer (score 17):

I think something easier would be `\renewcommand\refname{}`

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if `\tableofcontents` is used, then an odd entry with no title, but page number, is added to the ToC.

Comment: Moreover, space-wise, a section will still be set, perhaps leaving an unwanted (large) vertical gap between text and references.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using biblatex:

```
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{}
```

Comment: `\printbibliography[heading=none]` as in [Apteryx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38471/apteryx)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257819/35864). Would be slightly nicer, I think.