# Change reference title size

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, header-footer, fontsize, books

I need to change the font size of reference title in `ctexbook`. An obvious way is redefining the `\bibname` macro. However, that would change the heading as well. For example,
`\renewcommand{\bibname}{\zihao{2} 参考文献}`
leads to [image]

So, my question is how to change the font size of the title without affecting the heading. Since `biblatex` is incompatible with many other packages, I would prefer non-biblatex solution.

Comment: the size of the references title is almost always defined in the document class; often it's simply an application of `\chapter` or `\section`.  so unless the document class is known, it's not possible to help.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I've edited to  emphasize the document class `ctexbook`. I guess the problem exists in other document classes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Motivated by Gonzalo Medina's answer from [How to remove the “References” title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132646/how-to-remove-the-references-title), I use `\patchcmd` to modify the definition of `\thebibliography`.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*{\bibname}}{\chapter*{\zihao{2}\bibname}}{}{}
```

gives what I want.