# How to remove the "Bibliography" title in book class

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, books, etoolbox, bibunits

Here:

[How to remove the "References" title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132646/how-to-remove-the-references-title)

Gonzalo Medina suggests to use:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*{\refname}}{}{}{}
```

to remove the word "References" before the references; this works great for the article class; how to do the same for the book class?

Comment: Try `\makeatletter\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*{\bibname}\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}}{}{}{}\makeatother`

Comment: It works! Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments ...

Comment: @Mensch While that is a valid reason to close a question, I thought it would be better in this case to make the comment  into a CW answer. It would be useful to someone else with the same problem.

Comment: I too agree with `Davislor`....

Answer (score 1):

Promoting the comment by @moewe to a Community Wiki answer:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*{\bibname}\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```