# How to remove the "References" title (when I have only main bibliography)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, polyglossia

As a continue to this question: [How to remove the "References" title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132646/how-to-remove-the-references-title)
I want to remove the it for the main bibliography of  the document and not only for sections (I have only one bibliography)...

I'm using `XeTeX` and `BibTeX`....

MWE:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.6.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 linkcolor=blue}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Bellefair}
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern -3pt
  \hbox to \textwidth{\hfill\vrule height 0.4pt width .4\textwidth}
  \kern 2.6pt
}}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
שלום

\begin{english}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{bib1}

\end{english}
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Not understood. Even if you only have one bibliography there should still be a title for it so the reader knows what it is.

Comment: @daleif - Because it's Hebrew and English text it makes many problems, so I want to add it manually... 
So I want to know how to remove the title (this is what cause the problem)

Comment: And now you know why we always ask for a full but minimal example such that we know what we are dealing with

Comment: Yes, I know, but instead of change many things I prefer to remove the bib title...

Comment: That is not what I meant. Its so we know exactly what you are doing. Do you have packages that affect the bibliography, like natbib. You give no info....

Comment: @daleif - I added MWE :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is plain `scrartcl` and no `natbib` the bibliography is probably controlled by `scrartcl`

In its source we find that

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bib@heading}{}
\makeatother
```

should completely remove the header including the spacing above and below the heading.

Comment: It's works!! The only change I need to do is `\renewcommand*{\bib@heading}{}` because if I'm what you wrote it says that the commands is already defined...

Comment: @heblyx right, fixed

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
\addto\captionsenglish{% Added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand{\refname}{}
}
```

[image: a]

A chapter with a blank title will produce a vertical blank space that could be removed for use by the bibliography.

Updated last part of your MWE

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\addto\captionsenglish{% Added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand{\refname}{}
}


\begin{document}    
    שלום

    \vspace*{-40pt} % remove the vertical space produced by a chapter with no title
    \begin{english} 
        \nocite{*}  
        \bibliographystyle{plain}   
        \bibliography{examplebib}
    \end{english}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not working :-\...

Comment: This line `\addto\captionsenglish{...}` don't let it work, if I remove it - it works fine :)